# SQL over TLS using Let's Encrypt on Raspberry pi

Tags: mysql, certificate

I want to be able to connect to a database hosted on a Raspberry Pi (mysql-server) from a C# application. In the real world professionals use a Webservice for this, but I want to use the SQL-connector for C#.

I successfully pulled this off using a certificate from Comodo.
See https://tutorials.pieterjan.pro/?a=Webdesign_Hosting_ExternHosten_HTTPS_SSL_SQL-TLS&lang=nl

I already installed a certificate from Let's Encrypt for pieterjan.pro. But when I configure mysql to use this certificate it doesn't work. While I actually did the same thing.

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

contains:

```
ssl
ssl-cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/pieterjan.pro/fullchain.pem
ssl-key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/pieterjan.pro/privkey-nopassword.key
```

The key-file has been reproduced with openSSL, So it wouldn't be password-protected. The paths to the cert and key are correct. Why can't I use SQL over TLS using a LetsEncrypt Certificate?

```
pi@pieterjan:~ $ mysql -p -u root
Enter password:
mysql> show variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                      |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | DISABLED                                                   |
| have_ssl      | DISABLED                                                   |
| ssl_ca        |                                                            |
| ssl_capath    |                                                            |
| ssl_cert      | /etc/letsencrypt/live/pieterjan.pro/fullchain.pem          |
| ssl_cipher    |                                                            |
| ssl_key       | /etc/letsencrypt/live/pieterjan.pro/privkey-nopassword.key |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT:

So far I've tested some things:

1) The error-log says:

```
SSL error: Unable to get certificate from '/etc/letsencrypt/live/pieterjan.pro/fullchain.pem'
```

2) The owner of the specified file is root:root

```
sudo ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/live/pieterjan.pro/fullchain.pem
-> user=root & group=root
```

3) The mysql-daemon was started by the mysql-user

```
ps -aux | grep mysql
-> mysql   /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

4) Therefore I tried to add the mysql-user to the root group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G root mysql
```

5) Double-check -> OK

```
sudo grep 'root' /etc/group
-> root:x:0:mysql
```

6) Inspection of certificate-files

```
sudo ls -la /etc/letsencrypt/live/pieterjan.pro/
-> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 Jan 18 13:14 cert.pem -> ../../archive/pieterjan.pro/cert1.pem
-> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   38 Jan 18 13:14 chain.pem -> ../../archive/pieterjan.pro/chain1.pem
-> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   42 Jan 18 13:14 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/pieterjan.pro/fullchain1.pem
```

They appear to be just symlinks.

7) Tracked the file down which is mentioned in the error-log

```
sudo ls -la /etc/letsencrypt/archive/pieterjan.pro/fullchain1.pem
-> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root
```

The certificate is readable for owner/group/world

Despite the fact that the mysql-user is in the root-group, mysql-server is still unable to read the certificate (after restarting mysql off course).

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late replying here but I suspect the problem is that Let's Encrypt supplies certificates in PKCS #8 format, whereas MySQL needs them in PKCS #1 format. You will need to convert the key each time it is renewed. A hook along these lines should do the trick:

```
openssl rsa -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem -out /etc/mysql/privkey.pem && systemctl restart mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I Believe the problem you are experiencing is that MySQL being a closed service requires a certificate authority not the fullchain.pem

AFAIK (happy to be corrected if wrong), MySQL is fine to use with an internal CA certificate because it is not publicly accessed and a single public private key-pair and CA is responsible for the entire MySQL infrastructure.

Percona has a lovely little tutorial I've run on my Pi [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/06/22/setting-up-mysql-ssl-and-secure-connections/#setup) which uses the key-generation method from the mysql Oracle mainline site [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html#creating-ssl-files-using-openssl-unix-command-line)

If it still doesn't work, check [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/451487/configured-mysql-for-ssl-but-ssl-is-still-disabled)